# Error NullPointerException haciendo ejercicio Rebota Pelota

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio, donde el objetivo es que una pelota rebote en un `JFrame`, después de hacer clic en el `JButton dale` 
El problema, es que el IDE me arroja una excepción de tipo `NullPointerException`, pero no puedo encontrar cuál es la variable que está en NULL.
ERROR

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at ProyectoPelotaPractica.LaminaBotones.comienza(UsoThreads.java:130)

¿Alguien podría probarlo y ayudarme, por favor?

Este es el código:

```
public class UsoThreads {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Marco miMarco=new Marco();
        miMarco.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        miMarco.setVisible(true);

    }

}

class Marco extends JFrame{

    public Marco() {
        setBounds(400,300,600,400);
        setTitle("Rebota Pelota");
        LaminaPelota miLamina=new LaminaPelota();
        add(miLamina,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        LaminaBotones milamina2=new LaminaBotones();
        add(milamina2,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }   
}

class Pelota extends JPanel{

    private double x=10;
    private double y=10;
    private static final int TAMX=15;
    private static final int TAMY=15;
    private double speedX=1;
    private double speedY=1;

    public void mover(Rectangle2D limite) {
        x+=speedX;
        y+=speedY;

        if(x<limite.getMinX()) {
            x=limite.getMinX();
            speedX=-speedX;
        }

        if(x+TAMX>limite.getMaxX()) {
            x=limite.getMaxX()-TAMX;
            speedX=-speedX;
        }

        if(y<limite.getMinY()) {
            y=limite.getMinY();
            speedY=-speedY;
        }

        if(y+TAMY>limite.getMaxY()) {
            y=limite.getMaxY()-TAMY;
            speedY=-speedY;
        }

    }

    public Ellipse2D dibujarPelota() {
        return new Ellipse2D.Double(x,y,TAMX,TAMY);
    }

}

class LaminaPelota extends JPanel{

    private ArrayList<Pelota>arrayPelota=new ArrayList<Pelota>();

    public void agregarPelota(Pelota b) {
        arrayPelota.add(b);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){ 
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D) g; 

    for(Pelota e:arrayPelota) {
        g2.fill(e.dibujarPelota());
    }


    }

}

class LaminaBotones extends JPanel{

    public LaminaBotones() {
        JButton dale=new JButton("Dale");
        JButton salir=new JButton("Salir");
        dale.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                comienza();
            }

        });

        salir.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.exit(0);
            }


        });
        add(dale);
        add(salir);
    }

    public void comienza() {
        Pelota pelota=new Pelota();
        lamina.agregarPelota(pelota);
        for(int i=1;i<=3000;i++) {
            pelota.mover(lamina.getBounds());
            lamina.paint(lamina.getGraphics());

        }
    }

    private LaminaPelota lamina;
}
```

Comment: Hola Gonzalo, el error debe mostrar un stacktrace con los ficheros relacionados y la línea en concreto donde da el fallo. Por favor, comparte esa información también porque es esencial para limitar el alcance del problema y ayudarte de forma más sencilla. Lee [ask] para más información.

Comment: @Gonzalo offtopic deberias aplicar algun algoritmo para el rebote de la pelota

Comment: Es corecto, voy a mostrar el error, o excepcion! El algoritmo se encuentra x-rw! Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la clase "LaminaBotones" la variable "lamina" (tipo "LaminaPelota") no está inicializada. Al hacer click en el botón "Dale" se llama al método "comienza()" donde se utiliza dicha variable. Saludos

Comment: Hola Luis, como inicializas? Gracias!

Comment: Ya que en la clase 'Marco' estas instanciando tanto 'LaminaPelota' como 'LaminaBotones' sería bueno que a 'LaminaBotones' le pases como parámetro 'LaminaPelota'. En el constructor de 'LaminaBotones' asignas el parámetro recibido a la variable 'lamina'.

Comment: Resolviste mi duda. Excelente.